# Java Swing and JComboBox Events

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` with multiple values in it. I need to be able to detect when the user clicks the `JComboBox` but does not change the currently selected item.

Neither `itemStateChanged` nor `actionPerformed` fire when this happens.

What event should I be using?

Answer (score 2):

How about recording the combo box's state when the mouse button is pressed, and comparing it to the value the box has when the mouse button is released?

- attach [a `MouseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the `JComboBox`
- override [the `mousePressed()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mousePressed%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) to record the box's state to a temp variable
- override [the `mouseReleased()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) to compare the box's value to the temp variable's value

At this point, it's a simple equality check.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MouseListener` to the `JComboBox` using its `addMouseListener` method. You will want to extend `MouseAdapter` and override only the `mouseClicked` method.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. The user could click and release, and then select an item from the list. That doesn't seem to be the case the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

What if the user users the keyboard to open the popup and then uses the escape key to close the popup?

I would use a PopupMenuListener. This should handle both mouse and keyboard actions. The concept would be the same as other suggestions. When the popup is displayed you save the selected index. When is closes you compare the selected index to see it it has changed.

Comment: That is a good point. It is definitely possible the keyboard could be used.

Comment: If that's a situation you need to account for, you should update your question. Fewer people will see it down here as a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking specifically at right mouse click on items, so it's a slightly different problem.
But the solution for me was to

1. Subclass `JComboBox` substituting `getCellRenderer(`) with a subclassed `DefaultListCellRenderer`.
2. In the cell renderer intercept `getListCellRendererComponent()` which has `boolean isSelected`, `boolean cellHasFocus` parameters and can be used to watch for mouse events and do `list.setToolTipText()`.

I'm sure the non-final selection change will get there, where it can be intercepted.